# how to change Scene size in Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Under the modify tab you can chose from four standard scene size but i couldn't find any way to set specific size to the scene in the scene builder

Answer (score 1):

Modify -> Scene Size is a bit misleading: it does set the size of the Scene object but size of the root object. It's a kind of shortcut.

You can do the same by selecting the root object and changing the preferred size in the Inspector. This way, you can choose any size.